# Switching Hosting Company PHP GET Script Won't Work

Tags: php

I switched hosting accounts from DreamHost to InMotion Hosting... I used to use a script that worked fine on DreamHost but since the switch it creates a xml file but is empty. Any ideas?

```
<?php 
$xml = file_get_contents('ftp://USER:USER@aphrodite.WEB.net/exports/xml/products.xml');
file_put_contents('./pro_data/products.xml', $xml);
?>
```

I tried php version 5.5-7.0 same thing.

Comment: Error message I get wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0

Comment: Sounds like the error message is telling you what your problem is: the PHP configuration doesn't allow opening remote URLs.

Comment: "the error message is telling you what your problem is" Imagine that!

Answer (score 0):

In php.ini added the following to the file and save.

```
allow_url_fopen=on
```